# Codec h264_cuvid is not supported

Tags: ffmpeg, nvidia, hardware-acceleration, video-codecs

======================= **Environment** =======================
System: ubuntu 18.04
Architecture: x86_64
Display Card: NVIDIA GeForce 820m
Display Card Driver: NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-390.87
gcc: 6.5.0
CUDA: 9.1.85 (also tried 9.0.176)
FFmpeg: 3.4 (also tried 4.0, 4.1)

==================== **FFmpeg Compilation** ====================

```
./configure \
  --prefix="$DIR_BUILD" \
  --bindir="$DIR_BIN" \
  --enable-cuda \
  --enable-cuvid \
  --enable-nvenc \
  --enable-nonfree \
  --enable-libnpp \
  --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include \
  --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

======================= **Verification** =======================
Driver Verification:
(I have downgrade my gcc from 7.3 to 6.5, I don't know why there still shows gcc version 7.3)

```
$ cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  390.87  Tue Aug 21 12:33:05 PDT 2018
GCC version:  gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04)
```

**CUDA Verification:**

```
$nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Nov__3_21:07:56_CDT_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.1, V9.1.85

$./deviceQuery
Rsult = PASS

$./bandwidthTest
Result = PASS
```

**FFmpeg Decoder Verification:**

```
$ ffmpeg -codecs | grep cuvid
ffmpeg version 3.4.5 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.5.0 (Ubuntu 6.5.0-2ubuntu1~18.04) 20181026
  configuration: --prefix=/home/cavalry/Downloads/compile_ffmpeg/ffmpeg_build --bindir=/home/cavalry/Downloads/compile_ffmpeg/bin --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-nvenc --enable-nonfree --enable-libnpp --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
 DEV.LS h264                 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 (decoders: h264 h264_v4l2m2m h264_vdpau h264_cuvid ) (encoders: h264_nvenc h264_v4l2m2m h264_vaapi nvenc nvenc_h264 )
 DEV.L. hevc                 H.265 / HEVC (High Efficiency Video Coding) (decoders: hevc hevc_cuvid ) (encoders: nvenc_hevc hevc_nvenc hevc_vaapi )
 DEVIL. mjpeg                Motion JPEG (decoders: mjpeg mjpeg_cuvid ) (encoders: mjpeg mjpeg_vaapi )
 DEV.L. mpeg1video           MPEG-1 video (decoders: mpeg1video mpeg1video_vdpau mpeg1_v4l2m2m mpeg1_cuvid )
 DEV.L. mpeg2video           MPEG-2 video (decoders: mpeg2video mpegvideo mpegvideo_vdpau mpeg2_v4l2m2m mpeg2_cuvid ) (encoders: mpeg2video mpeg2_vaapi )
 DEV.L. mpeg4                MPEG-4 part 2 (decoders: mpeg4 mpeg4_v4l2m2m mpeg4_vdpau mpeg4_cuvid ) (encoders: mpeg4 mpeg4_v4l2m2m )
 D.V.L. vc1                  SMPTE VC-1 (decoders: vc1 vc1_vdpau vc1_v4l2m2m vc1_cuvid )
 DEV.L. vp8                  On2 VP8 (decoders: vp8 vp8_v4l2m2m vp8_cuvid ) (encoders: vp8_v4l2m2m vp8_vaapi )
 DEV.L. vp9                  Google VP9 (decoders: vp9 vp9_v4l2m2m vp9_cuvid ) (encoders: vp9_vaapi )
```

**FFmpeg Encoder Verification:**

```
$ ffmpeg -codecs | grep nvenc 
ffmpeg version 3.4.5 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.5.0 (Ubuntu 6.5.0-2ubuntu1~18.04) 20181026
  configuration: --prefix=/home/cavalry/Downloads/compile_ffmpeg/ffmpeg_build --bindir=/home/cavalry/Downloads/compile_ffmpeg/bin --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-nvenc --enable-nonfree --enable-libnpp --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
 DEV.LS h264                 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 (decoders: h264 h264_v4l2m2m h264_vdpau h264_cuvid ) (encoders: h264_nvenc h264_v4l2m2m h264_vaapi nvenc nvenc_h264 )
 DEV.L. hevc                 H.265 / HEVC (High Efficiency Video Coding) (decoders: hevc hevc_cuvid ) (encoders: nvenc_hevc hevc_nvenc hevc_vaapi )
```

================== **Exec ffmepg command line** ===================

All things seem goes right, then I executed the following command:
`ffmpeg -c:v h264_cuvid -i ./holidy.mp4 output.mkv`
But it turns out:
`[h264_cuvid @ 0x55f93a512200] Codec h264_cuvid is not supported.`

**Here is the whole information:**

```
$ ffmpeg -c:v h264_cuvid -i ./holidy.mp4 output.mkv
ffmpeg version 3.4.5 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.5.0 (Ubuntu 6.5.0-2ubuntu1~18.04) 20181026
  configuration: --prefix=/home/cavalry/Downloads/compile_ffmpeg/ffmpeg_build --bindir=/home/cavalry/Downloads/compile_ffmpeg/bin --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-nvenc --enable-nonfree --enable-libnpp --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from './holidy.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isomavc1iso6
    creation_time   : 2018-01-29T09:18:23.000000Z
    album           : Yinyuetai
    artist          : yinyuetai.com
    comment         : Yinyuetai-1TR1166
    date            : 01/29/18 17:18:23
  Duration: 00:04:15.21, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4210 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 4087 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-01-29T09:18:23.000000Z
      handler_name    : 264@GPAC0.5.1-DEV-rev5472
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 120 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-01-29T09:17:31.000000Z
      handler_name    : Sound Media Handler
[h264_cuvid @ 0x55f3e05ca1c0] Codec h264_cuvid is not supported.
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (h264_cuvid) -> mpeg4 (native))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> ac3 (native))
Error while opening decoder for input stream #0:0 : Invalid argument
```

I have tried width CUDA9.0, CUDA9.1, FFmpeg3.4, FFmpeg4.0, FFmpeg 4.1, but it reports the same error. Can anyone help me? I will appreciate you greatly !

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to this problem?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just give up.

Unfortunately, GeForce 820m is a Fermi based GPU without cuvid at all.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Nvidia Video Encode and Decode GPU Support Matrix](https://developer.nvidia.com/video-encode-decode-gpu-support-matrix#Decoder)([snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9XtX.png)),
GeForce 820m support NVENC & NVDEC. If my understanding is correct, a Nvidia graphic card that support NVENC & NVDEC should support h264_cuvid decoder in FFmpeg as well. So I think the answer of @halfelf was wrong.